# Checkbox not showing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import moment from "moment";

class orders extends React.Component {
  state= {
    orders: [],
    checked: false
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadOrders();
  }

  loadOrders() {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `http://localhost:4200/api/orders/getallorders`
      }).then(res => {
        this.setState({orders: res.data.orders})

    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  handleCheck(e){
   this.setState({
    checked: e.target.checked
   })
   }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className={'container'}>
        <div className={'row'} style={{marginTop: '16px'}}>
          <h4 className={'col m6'} style={{margin: '0', padding: '0'}}>Orders</h4>
          <div className={'col m6'}>
            <input id ="checkbox_id" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} onChange={this.handleCheck}/>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div className={'row'}>
        {this.state.orders.map(order => {
            return (
              <div key={order._id}  className={'col m3 center teal lighten-5'} style={{padding: '0'}}>
                <div className={'card-content'} style={{padding: '16px'}}>
                <p>{order._id}</p>
                <p style={{marginTop: '4px'}}>{moment(order.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}</p>
                <p style={{marginTop: '4px'}}>{order.shippingstatus}</p>
                <Link to={{ pathname: '/admin/orders/vieworder', state: {order} }}> <button className={'btn'} style={{marginTop: '8px'}}>View Order</button> </Link>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
        })}
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default orders;
```

Hello everyone, I'm using react and I have a very strange problem, the `checkbox` is not showing at all in the browser, I searched online but didn't find any answers that could help, any idea why it's not showing and how to fix it?

I tried adding and removing "PreventDefaults" but no use.

Comment: Weird. I just tried on my machine and it's showing. What browser are you using?

Comment: From where come these classNames? Is it from a global css? Maybe you have some issue with your stylesheet.

Comment: Is the input appearing in your DOM tree ?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya chrome, also tried firefox and it didn't show up

Comment: @Aldo its from https://materializecss.com/

Comment: @Treycos what do you mean? how can I check it?

Comment: You can see it from your browser console (ctrl + shift + I on chrome, ctrl + shift + k on firefox). The DOM/tree inspector will show you every element in your generated DOM

Comment: @Treycos it does show but in a weird way here is picture: https://imgur.com/a/nFu7y7Q

Comment: So at least, we know your input is there. This seems to be a CSS problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out to be an error with https://materializecss.com I should have added `<form action="#">` as in their docs https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html